# how to avoid sequence using XSD

Tags: schema, xsd, xsd-validation

i want a particular sequence to be generated in a random manner

```
<item>
 <i1>abc</i1>
 <i2>pqr</i2>
</item>
```

now how can i make an xsd where `<i1>` can come before `<i2>` ?

Comment: please be mindful when entering code (especially html/xml-like) in a question/comment. Use Code blocks and/or backtick escaping

Comment: Also, since you are new here, remember to accept the answer when someone answers the question adequately. You can upvote it if you really want to as well :)

Answer (score 2):

use the 'all' indicator as shown on the [w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp)